# How to get the full text with first and last matching in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
pr_text pr_abcd_text pr-efgh-text
```

I want that part which starts with `pr-` and ends with `-text`.

The result will be `pr-efgh-text`

How can I do that?

Comment: Yes. I can do it easily with for loop. But need some optimized code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//1. splitted the text by space, which returns Array
//2. filter the Array, check the text starts with ('pr-' and '-text')
let output = `pr_text pr_abcd_text pr-efgh-text`.split(/\s+/)
    .filter(a => a.startsWith('pr-') && a.endsWith('-text'));
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Please add some explaination on how this works and why this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` functions of JavaScript

```
var x = "pr_text pr_abcd_text pr-efgh-text"
x = x.split(" ")
var res = x.filter(d => d.startsWith("pr-") && d.endsWith("-text"))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just check the string with `.split` like this:

```
function getString(str) {
 return str.split(' ').filter(item => {
        const splitted = item.split('-');
        if(splitted.length === 3) {
          console.log(item);
          return splitted[0] === 'pr' && splitted[2] === 'text';
        }
        return false;
    })
};

console.log(getString("pr_text pr_abcd_text pr-efgh-text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array of the words with the specific prefix and suffix.

```js
let text = "pr_text pr_abcd_text pr-efgh-text";
let matched = text.match(/(pr-)(\w+?)(-text)/ig);

console.log(matched) // ['pr-efgh-text']
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = "pr_text pr_abcd_text pr-efgh-text";

const startIndex = text.indexOf("pr-");
const endIndex = text.indexOf("-text") + "-text".length;
const output = text.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/SqtJgm/1

```js
const regex = /^(pr-)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-text)$/g;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('^(pr-)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-text)$', 'g')

const str = `pr-e912381231example-text`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```